# Credential provider in win8

Tags: windows-8, credential-providers

I want to login to my user account automatically using code.
I am using Windows 8.
I tried to use Credential Provider sample. I compiled the sample in the SDK and add the dll to the registry as described in the readme.

when I lock my computer I can see the regular user account tile.
only when I press on Esc I see the 2 new tiles that were added in the sample.
then if I press on one of them, and try any kind of password, I just get back to the previous page where I had only the regular tile. and cannot login.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the expected behavior.

If, when you type your password, you are immediately redirected to the tile selection without an error message, then your credential provider crashed.

I suggest [remote debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) in order to find the source of your problem. If that's not an option for you, you can always write logs.

In case you don't know, you can start windows in safe mode to be able to login even when your credential provider crashes.