# Is it possible to create a program that changes/customizes how a user logs into their account in Windows?

Tags: windows, customization

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I was wondering if it would be possible to change the way a user logs in using Windows. I currently have Windows 8.

What I mean by this question is that instead of a user entering a password to log into their account or using a finger print scanner, we can have something like a matrix of numbers (like the movie) that keeps scrolling up or down. A user has to click in a certain way or combination. Or the user has to drag certain numbers over others in different columns (some sort of idea along those lines using some sort of algorithm).

Is it even possible to change the way a user logs into their account on Windows? I do have an old laptop I can mess around with.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but it is not something that a novice programmer could even hope to accomplish.

Comment: The magic phrase is "[credential provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125962/credential-provider-in-win8)".

Answer (score 0):

Windows has 3 built-in Sign-in Options

1. Login using a Password

   Login using a Picture Password (you login using three gestures saved on a picture)

   Login using a 4 Digit PIN

Apart from this you can get rid of Windows Sign-in option by running **'netplwiz'** in run box and unchecking the box that says *“Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer”.*

You can then use software like 
[Eusing Maze Lock](http://www.eusing.com/mazelock/pclock.htm)

[XUS PC Lock](http://www.xussoft.com/xuspclock/index.html)

Also using fingerprints is possible if you have a fingerprint reader. Check if 'Biometrics\Credential Provider' registry entry for this is disabled if you are unable to get a fingerprint option in Sign-in options.